# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el contenido de la primera columna de mi registro seleccionado dentro de un treeview?

Tags: python

> No pongo código porque es una pregunta sencilla, no creo que haga falta

Ya he obtenido el contenido de las otras columnas mediante el índice del item seleccionado, pero de la primera que es la que el treeview crea por defecto no me deja.

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. ¿Cuáles "otras columnas"? (...) _pero de la primera que es la que el treeview crea por defecto no me deja_: ¿por qué decís que no te deja?

Answer (score 0):

La columna creada por default tiene un trato especial. No se puede agregar datos a ella usando el parametro values (ya que se salta la columna default), si no que se trabaja con ella usando la opción text. Acabo de probar y ni siquiera se puede usar el método set para obtener y establecer su valor.

Todo esto significa que la columna solo puede ser afectada por el método item (que permite obtener datos sobre el item en particular).

#### Solución

Usaré un código de ejemplo que se encarga de crear un treeview que muestra todos los caracteres ascii entre "a" y "z". Al hacer doble clic sobre un item especifico, se imprime el id del caracter.

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def get_values(event):
    (sel,) = tree.selection()
    print(tree.item(sel, "text"))

tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=["char"])

tree.heading("#0", text="ID")
tree.column("#0", width=50)

tree.heading("char", text="Caracter")
tree.column("char", width=50)

for i in range(ord("a"), ord("z") + 1):
    tree.insert("", "end", text=i, values=[chr(i)])

tree.pack()
tree.bind("<Double-Button-1>", get_values)

root.mainloop()
```

En este código accedemos a la opción text del item, donde se aloja el valor de la columna.

#### Pero, ¿No existe una alternativa mejor?

La realidad, es que tratar una columna de modo diferente solo por que Tkinter así lo desea es terrible. Requiere código de más e innecesariamente complejo. Entonces, ¿No hay una manera de que la columna default no tenga ese trato especial, o en su defecto que esta columna no sea creada?

En realidad, no hay manera, pero podemos ocultar esa columna al usuario usando el argumento show="headings" del treeview. Entonces, gracias también a su trato especial, podremos "fingir" que la columna no existe.

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def get_values(event):
    (sel,) = tree.selection()
    # ahora que el id está alojado en una columna normal
    # podemos acceder a el como con cualquier otra columna.
    print(tree.set(sel, "id"))

# creamos la columna id, ya no usaremos la columna default.
tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=["id", "char"], show="headings")

# En lugar de usar la default, aclaramos la primera columna que usaremos.
tree.heading("id", text="ID")
tree.column("id", width=50)

tree.heading("char", text="Caracter")
tree.column("char", width=50)

for i in range(ord("a"), ord("z") + 1):
    # gracias a lo que hicimos, ahora podemos trabajar más comodos
    # pasando todos los valores a la opción values
    tree.insert("", "end", values=[i, chr(i)])

tree.pack()
tree.bind("<Double-Button-1>", get_values)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Genial amigo!!...de verdad muchísimas gracias eres un máquina , muchas gracias de nuevo por tu ayuda utilice el método item con el 'text' dentro y me funciono

Comment: De nada Leandro c: Por cierto, si mi respuesta te sirvió te agradecería que la aceptaras o votaras nwn